# How to read integers from a text file and store them in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a file named example.txt with 7 integers formatted as such,

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 6
>
> 7

My code is,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

int arr[7];

ifstream File;
File.open("example.txt");

int n = 0;
while (File >> arr[n]) {
    n++;
}
File.close();

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

This code works, because I already know how many integers are in the text file. What should I change in the code to make sure it works if I don't know how many integers are in the file? In other words, if someone were to change the number of integers in the text file, how do I make sure my code works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were almost C++ compliant there.

So I took the time to change a few lines of your code replacing the C-style array by a `vector`. That was the only thing missing to make it really C-free :). See the `****` comments when I changed stuff.

Use `vector` everytime, specially when you don't know the size of the list (and even if you know the size since you can `reserve` or `resize` or create the vector with the proper dimension at start.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>   // ****

using namespace std;

int main() {

vector<int> arr;   // ****

ifstream File;
File.open("example.txt");

int n;                     // ****
while (File >> n) {        // ****
    arr.push_back(n);      // ****
}
File.close();

for (auto n : arr) {      // ****
    cout << n << endl;    // ****
}

return 0;
}
```

Use `-std=c++11` flag to compile it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::vector` instead of a fixed size array.

With your existing code you can then use `push_back` to add an item at the end of a vector.

Or you can get all geeky and use `std::copy`, `std::istream_iterator` and `std::back_inserter`. I don't recommend that, really, but it can look impressive. And it can be fun to do.