# stock data from file into arrays c++

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I have this specific code to read integers from a text file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

bool contains_number(const string &c);

int main()
{
    int from[50], to[50];
    int count = 0;
    {
        string line1[50];
        ifstream myfile("test.txt");

        int a = 0;

        if (!myfile)
        {
            cout << "Error opening output file" << endl;
        }

        while (!myfile.eof())
        { 
            getline(myfile, line1[a]);

            if (contains_number(line1[a]))
            {
                count += 1;
                myfile >> from[a];
                myfile >> to[a];

                //cout << "from:" << from[a] << "\n";
                //cout << "to:" << to[a] << "\n";
            }
        }   
    }    
    return 0;
}

bool contains_number(const string &c)
{   
    return (c.find_first_of("1:50") != string::npos);
}
```

I need to stock these values of from[] and to[] in 2 arrays to use them n another function, I tried to create 2 arrays in a simple way and affect the values for example:

```
int x[], y[];
myfile >> from[a];
for(int i=0; i<50;i++)
{
    x[i] = from[i];
}
```

but it doesn't work. It seems that this way is only to read and display and a value in from will be deleted once another value comes.
Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read integers from a text file and store them in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549120/how-to-read-integers-from-a-text-file-and-store-them-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

You're not incrementing your array index `a` in your loop. This results in `line[0]`, `to[0]` and `from[0]` to be overwritten for every line in the file where `contains_number` returns true.

There is no reason for you to save your lines into memory. You can just process your lines as you go through the file (i.e. create a `string line` variable in your while loop).

Make sure you properly close your file handle.

Aside from that you should check your index bounds in the loop (a < 50), else you might be writing out of bounds of your arrays if your file has more numbers than 50.

A better solution yet would be to use [vectors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of arrays, especially if your file may contain any number of numbers.